# How to find the median of Bernoulli trials and $\bar{X} = (X_1 + X_2 + X_3)/3$?

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, median, bernoulli-distribution

Assume $X_{1}, X_{2}$ and $X_{3}$ are independent Bernoulli trials with $p=0.5 .$ Let $\bar{X}=\left(X_{1}+X_{2}+X_{3}\right) / 3$ and $M=\operatorname{median}\left(X_{1}, X_{2}, X_{3}\right)$.

(a) Find the joint distribution of $\bar{X}$ and $M$.

(b) Find the covariance and correlation between $\bar{X}$ and $M$.

I've already known that if we sum up Bernoulli trials with probability $p$ for $n$ times, we get a Binomial distribution, represented by $Y \sim  \operatorname{Bin}(n, p)$. Also, I've searched the median of Bernoulli on Wikipedia, says the median can be noted as

$$
M=
\begin{cases}0 & \text { if } p<1 / 2 \\ {[0,1]} & \text { if } p=1 / 2 \\ 1 & \text { if } p>1 / 2.\end{cases}
$$

But I think I lost some properties so that I cannot solve this problem.

Comment: As a start, if you enumerate the 8 possible triplets of $(X_1,X_2,X_3)$, the median, $M$, equals 0 with probability $.5$ and 1 with probability $.5$.  Enumerating all possible samples will help with answering both questions, for instance, $\mbox{Pr}[\bar{X} = 0, M = 0] = \mbox{Pr}[X_1=0,X_2=0,X_3=0] = 1/8$.

Comment: See the link, for deriving the order statistics of a discrete random variable in general.  You will find that my answer coincides.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic#Dealing_with_discrete_variables